# On Factoring and Discrete Logarithms in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, factoring, discrete-logarithms

Suppose $n$ is an integer with factorization $n = ab$, and $a, b$ **unknown** and not necessarily prime.

From this point forward, assume that we are free to choose $p$.

Let $g$ denote a primitive element of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. Therefore, $a = g^A, b = g^B$ for some $A,B \le p-1$. Without loss of generality, let $A \le B$ (in $\mathbb{Z}$). We can drop the equality if $n$ is not a perfect square in $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Q1:** Is it possible to choose $p, g$ such that $A$ is *small* relative to $p$?

**Q2:** Since there are $\phi(p-1)$ primitive elements in $\mathbb{F}_p$, an argument could be made that some primitive element $\gamma$ may yield $a = \gamma^\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is small relative to $p$, so the answer to Q1 is "probably yes". Suppose we choose a bound $\beta$, could we make a counting argument to estimate the probability that a randomly chosen primitive element $\gamma$ yields $a = \gamma^\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is small relative to $\beta$?

**Q3:** There are primes of special form where computing discrete logs is *easy* (i.e. polynomial time). For eg: Fermat Primes and primes where factors of $p-1$ are reasonably small where we could use Silver-Pohlig-Hellman discrete log algorithm. While $F_4 = 65537$ is the largest known Fermat prime and may not be suitable for large $n$ for our purposes, we are free to choose primes where factors of $p-1$ are reasonably small. For eg: primes of the form $2^mk +1$. It is known that there are infinitely many primes of this form.

Therefore, given a prime of the form $p = 2^mk + 1 > n$ can we find a primitive element $g \in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that it splits the two cofactors of $n$ into disjoint ranges containing consecutive powers of $g$ with $a \in [g^0,g^\beta]$ and $b \in [g^\beta, g^{p-1}]$ with $a = g^A$ and effectively searchable by brute force of the range $[g^0,g^\beta]$?

Comment: $A,B$ are not elements of $\Bbb{F}_p$. You cannot fix $g$ then let $p$ vary, so what do you mean with "is it possible to choose $p$".

Comment: I have edited the error you pointed out on $A,B \not \in \mathbb{F}_p$. We fix $p$ and then, of the $\phi(p-1)$ primitive elements, I am asking if we can choose a $g$ subject to the conditions. What is the probability of finding the smaller cofactor of $n$ (or even a multiple of it) in the small powers of $g$?

Comment: You didn't clarify "find a $p$ and $g$" in the question. Do you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots

Comment: Given $a$, for any $\epsilon >0$ it is not hard to find infinitely many $p,g$ such that $A/(p-1) < \epsilon$.

Comment: @reuns: We don't know $a$, though. We have only $n$ and we want to factor $a$ from $n$.

Comment: Every odd prime can be written as $2^mk+1$ , with the restriction $2^m>k$ , the prime is called Proth-prime and if I am informed right , it is unknown whether infintie many of them exist.

Comment: @Peter: You are right about the Proth primes and the unknown status of whether an infinite number of them exist. However, for this problem, we don't need $2^m k + 1$ to satisfy $2^m > k$. We can have $k$ consist of entirely smooth factors in order to make Silver-Pohlig-Hellman easy. Then this becomes finding the primitive element $g$ that splits the cofactors into a small range that is searchable by brute force, right. It just kicks the can down the road to finding an appropriate $g$. Is that right?